# How to query Application Insight data using Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-studio

I have the following connectivity options in my Azure Data Studio setup:

[image]

How can I connect may Azure Data Studio to an Application Insight instance?

Comment: If you Application Insights is Workspace-based then all data (in slightly different schema) is stored in Workspace. For instance, AppRequests represent requests table in Application Insights.

Comment: Sorry, not following. Can you elaborate or provide a link to documentation?

Comment: Application Insights has two type of resources - Classic (backed up by internal Kusto) and Workspace-based (backed by Azure Monitor Log Analytics Workspace). Here is how you can migrate your Classic resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In `Azure Portal`, Create a `Log Analytics workspace`.

[image]

- Copy the workspace ID which is useful for later to connect Azure DataStudio.

[image]

***Create Application Insights***

- Select the Resource Mode as `Workspace-based`.
- In `Log Analytics Workspace`, select the `Workspace` which we have created in the first step. Click on `Review + create`.

[image]

- Open the `Azure Data Studio` => `New Connection`.
- Provide the `Workspace ID` which we have copied from `Portal` => `Log Analytics Workspace`.
- In `Account` => Add `Account`  => Login with your `Azure Subscription ID`.
- Click on `Connect`.
  [image]

[image]

- You can see the Azure Data Studio is now connected to our provided Log Analytics Workspace.
  [image]
- Now you can query the logs by using the `New query` option.
  [image]

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/azure-monitor-logs-extension?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: This approach does not query the Application Insight data. It query diagnostics of how Application Insight operates. Mind the differences.

Comment: @AllanXu, this is not correct. In this case Diagnostic Settings exports data sent to Application Insights. Though I think you can achieve almost the same without extra export step by migrating Classic AI resource to Workspace-based.

Comment: @AllanXu - If you don't want the diagnostic of Application Insights please ignore the export part.

Comment: As I have already mentioned in the answer to select the resource mode of AI as Workspace based.Please refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource) once.

Comment: Then I even more confused. You added diagnostic settings to a separate log analytics workspace and pointed the data studio there. Does this approach work when you don't include diagnostic data step?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the steps where there is no AI diagnostic settings involved? The laser focus and the scope of this question is only AI data not its internal operational diagnostic data.

Comment: Sure,will ignore the AI diagnostic setting step and will update the answer.

Comment: @AllanXu - Please check the answer now.Do let me know if you want me to provide more details.